# Refused to apply style from <> because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to host my Django/ReactJS website using Heroku and everything seems to be running, however, the website actually doesn't show anything and when I used Inspect the console outputs errors such as

> Refused to apply style from 'https://algo-interact.herokuapp.com/static/css/main.59f208c7.chunk.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

I've looked into people having similar problems on the internet and most of the time it's just a routing error, however, I try to find the actual file that's indicated in the error log but it doesn't seem to be in my repository. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: how did you resolve this issue please